# Advice needed - Webview iOS application acceptance or workaround

Tags: ios, swift, web-applications

Client wants to publish an iOS application as a starting point for their product which at the moment will be entirely single web view driven. There will be some networking calls to resolve some of the URLs, but the sign in and all content will be entirely on single web view. On top of that there is push notifications, which will redirect user to different parts of the website based on payload. 
* They have an existing Android application that does this and they want an iOS counterpart.

[Appstore guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/) [state](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#minimum-functionality) an iOS can't be a repackaged website and will likely get rejected. The purpose of this question is to find out if any of you fellow devs have gone through similar experience, and if so what was the outcome / recommendations to proceed.

- The mobile apps will have native components in future, but at this moment as a starting point it's not the case.

Thanks